# Array sobrepondo índices já declarados

Tags: javascript, array, array-push

Estou estudando a utilização de objetos em js, me deparei com a seguinte situação. Ao solicitar a criação de um novo usuário o código deveria dar um push() no meu array com o objeto informado e quando eu criasse um novo usuário incluir o novo. Acontece que ao fazer a leitura do userlist o array aparece sobreposto com os dados do ultimo usuário criado.

```html
    <script>
        var qntdcc = 0;
        var userlist = [];
        var pessoa = {
            nome: '', 
            usuario: '', 
            senha: '', 
            saldo: 0.0,
            ag: 0, 
            cc: 0, 
            sacar: function(valor){}, 
            depositar: function(valor){}, 
        }
        function conta(nome, usuario, senha){
            const novoUsuario = pessoa
            novoUsuario.nome = nome
            novoUsuario.usuario = usuario
            novoUsuario.senha = senha
            novoUsuario.saldo = 0
            novoUsuario.ag = 1
            if(novoUsuario.cc == qntdcc){
                qntdcc++;
                novoUsuario.cc = qntdcc;
            } else { novoUsuario.cc = qntdcc }
            userlist.push(novoUsuario)
            return 0
        }
    </script>
```

Imaginei que puder se tratar de uma questão dos tipos de variáveis usadas(var, let e const), mas acabo recebendo o mesmo retorno. Acredito que o erro possa estar na lógica desenvolvida mas não consegui identificar esse ponto.

[image: Trecho do código que desenvolvi]

[image: Resposta do comportamento do código no console chrome]

Comment: Obs.: Pensei também que pudesse ser a declaração da variável e que uma estaria sobrepondo a outra porém nesse caso a primeira gravação não deveria ser sobreposta, cheguei a adicionar o return pra encerrar a função sempre que chegasse ao fim da rotina mas também não resolveu.

Comment: Coloque o código editável para que possamos ajudar você.

Comment: @Leandro perdão, já adicionei! Como estou usando o js dentro do arquivo html ele não gera visualização mas acredito que já auxilie.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: @Comunidade, imagino que agora esteja mais direcionada ao foco da pergunta.

Answer (score -5):

Não tem muito código pra que possa analizar, mas o que você tem ai acho que é uma questão de referência de objeto.

Recomendo estudar sobre [referencias e valores em JS](https://www.braziljs.org/p/diferencas-entre-valor-e-referencia-em-javascript#:%7E:text=Por%20Valor%3A%20Significa%20criar%20uma,(alias)%20para%20o%20original.), mas basicamente quando você faz o seguinte:

```js
var pessoa = {
            nome: '', 
            usuario: '', 
            senha: '', 
            saldo: 0.0,
            ag: 0, 
            cc: 0, 
            sacar: function(valor){}, 
            depositar: function(valor){}, 
        }
            const novoUsuario = pessoa
```

Seu objeto `novoUsuario` agora tem uma **REFERÊNCIA** de pessoa, e quando você faz por exemplo

```
novoUsuario.nome = "Bla bla nome"
```

você na verdade está modificando ambos os objetos, já que o que vc tem é uma referencia e não um Valor propriamente dito.

O que dá pra fazer pra contornar isso é você criar um novo objeto a partir do objeto pessoa fazendo um spread dele.

ficaria assim:

```
const novoUsuario = {...pessoa}
```

Dessa forma agora você está criando de fato um objeto diferente, e não uma referencia de pessoa.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado @AugustoVasques, realmente. Após ler o artigo que me recomendou eu pude entender melhor o que esta explicando. Quando eu defino que minha variável ali no momento irá receber um objeto eu especifico que será apenas um e que ele não poderá ser alterado, porém a especificação de "{...pessoa}" determina que a variável poderá receber diferentes pessoas, expliquei com a situação mas pude abstrair o conceito. Muito obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Por nada, que bom que funcionou.

Comment: @GabrielGaldinoCardoso , não fui eu quem fiz indicação alguma. Inclusive não recomendo a abordagem usada nessa resposta pois induz a erro. Isso que foi ensinado é chamado shallow copy ou cópia superficial e não deve ser usada para instanciar objetos pois o seu uso embute um efeito colateral nas instancias é o compartilhamento implícito de referências em propriedades cujo o tipo não seja primitivo veja esse exemplo https://ideone.com/iIu8X0 mostrando na prática o porque não deve utilizar essa abordagem.

Comment: @GabrielGaldinoCardoso , a abordagem correta é definir uma classe e a partir dessa classe instanciar objetos com o operador [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). Veja o mesmo exemplo anterior usando funções construtoras https://ideone.com/lPwSJb e mesmo exemplo usando uma declaração de classe https://ideone.com/UlOryV.

Comment: @GabrielGaldinoCardoso Complementando o comentário do Augusto, uma solução ainda melhor é que o construtor já receba os dados necessários para criar uma `Pessoa` (ou seja, você faz algo como `new Pessoa('Fulano', 'username', 'senha')`, em vez de criar a pessoa pra só depois setar os dados - [ler aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052) para mais detalhes). Isso garante que a pessoa já é criada com os dados necessários. Ou seja, ficaria assim: https://ideone.com/x6i5zX

Comment: Outra coisa, a resposta que foi apagada tinha um detalhe: o jeito que foi feito ali cria os métodos `sacar` e `depositar` toda hora (cada instância possui uma nova "cópia" desses métodos, o que é redundante e desnecessário). Isso pode ser evitado com classes, veja a diferença: https://ideone.com/1FYISa

Comment: @AugustoVasques muito bom, poste sua resposta para que eu possa marcar como correta. Augusto, realmente comecei a ter erros posteriormente com a solução apresentada, após inserir diversos usuários a função de deposito não estava mais depositando nos usuários corretos somente no primeiro mesmo indicando a referencia do objeto que estava buscando o valor não era setado. Agradeço pela orientação pois assim posso aderir boas práticas de programação já no inicio.